# How to return profile id using paypal subscription button?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am using Paypal subscription button to subscribe the item,I have successfully subscribe the item but in response I get (transaction id,signature,cc,transaction status,cost,currency_code custom_msg) but i need profile_id(subscription id) for that particular subscription also.because when I unsubscribe the item,I need profile_id to unsubscribe it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [IPN](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/) to get the details of the transaction back to your system.  This will contain the transaction as well as the profile id.  You will receive an IPN each time the profile bills.

Comment: Thanks,but I have already enabled IPN,This is my step:-
1.Click Profile on the My Account tab.
2.Click Instant Payment Notification Preferences in the Selling Preferences column.
3.Click Choose IPN Settings to specify your listener’s URL and activate the listener.

Comment: This should then return the information to you that you are needing.  Are you not getting it back in IPN?

Comment: i am getting response with (transaction id,signature,cc,transaction status,cost,currency_code custom_msg) but not getting profile_id

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the solution, I have used paypal_nvp gem with GetTransactionDetails API to find the profile id for particular subscription.

```
    p = PaypalNVP.new(true{ :user => "o.bonn_1237393081_biz_api1.solisoft.net", :pass => "1237393093", :cert => "AU2Yv5COwWPCfeYLv34Z766F-gfNAzX6LaQE6VZkHMRq35Gmite-bMXu", :url => "https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp" })
       data = {
        :method => "GetTransactionDetails",
        :TRANSACTIONID =>params[:tx]
       }
       response = p.call_paypal(data)

 profile_id = response["SUBSCRIPTIONID"]
```

for further information you can go to https://github.com/solisoft/paypal_nvp url